# Azure devops server configuration utility error

Tags: azure, team-foundation-server

I wanted to upgrade my Team foundation server to Azure DevOps Server RC2 and for that I installed it through installer file. Now after installing whenever I am starting the server console,it's showing me this error:

[image: The Error message]

The error is 'could not find the C:..\web.config'
I have tried to reinstall it several time also deleting the installed file location (i.e C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019) to start the installation from scratch but after installation it remembers the configuration that I have done earlier for tfs, I also want to delete it to start the fresh installation. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Okay, i have recently found the solution for it. I have messed up with configuration of tfs so i have to uninstall application tier From command prompt, By going into 'C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019\Tools' and execute 'TfsConfig setup /uninstall:ApplicationTier' command to unconfigure TFS Application Tier. After that this i have restarted my application and this error message get removed.

Comment: I`ll believe that the production version of the Azure DevOps Server will not have that issue. Because today TFS does not need to uninstall before version upgrade.